# Conectar 2 archivos en VS Code de distintas carpetas

Tags: html, css, vs

creo que lo que quiero hacer es simple, pero no logro entender por qué no me sale.

Estoy trabajando en una carpeta llamada Codigos, dentro de esa carpeta quise poner las vistas (los html) en una subcarpeta llamada Paginas.
Como los archivos css los dejo en la carpeta Codigos, cdo abro los html en el servidor, aparecen sin estilo. Entonces quiero conectarlos con la nueva ruta.
Por ejemplo tengo una archivo experiencia.html (que está en la carpeta Paginas que quiero conectar con un archivo estilo_experiencia.css (que está en la carpeta Codigos) Supuse que debería hacer:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Codigos/estilo_experiencia.css">

Pero no funciona. Alguien me ayuda a entender dónde está el error y cómo debería ser la ruta para conectar el css con el html?

Gracias.
```

Comment: Hola colega! Pues mira, hace rato me paso lo mismo que a ti pero no encontre otra manera de enlazar los archivos a si como tu queres, por ejemplo debes especificar bien:

***CARPETAprincipa***l
adentro de esa carpeta estan dos carpetas carpetas mas, ***CARPETAHTML***, ***CARPETACSS*** entonces para enlazar el archivo de css que esta en la ***CARPETACSS*** se haria asi  ***href="CARPETAprincipal/CARPETACSS/archivo.css"***

Comment: @Sam Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Intenté como me dijiste. Cree una carpeta de css llamada Estilos que está dentro de la principal que es Codigos. Entonces, hago: <link rel="stylesheet" href="Codigos/Estilos/estilo_experiencia.css">    y no pasa nada, sigue sin verse el códig css en la página.

Answer (score 0):

Si dentro de la carpeta Codigos está el fichero estilo_experiencia.css y la carpeta Paginas con el .html. Lo siguiente debería funcionar:

```
href="../Codigos/estilo_experiencia.css">
```

Comment: Hola Jair, perdón, no había visto tu respuesta. Estuve intentando resolver otros asuntos. Ya tengo casi lista la página. Probé tu solución, que es bastante lógica, pero no funcionó, no sé por qué. Así que seguiré probando. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Volví a leer tu problema, desde tu fichero html tienes que poner ../ por cada carpeta hacia atras. Creo que lo que tienes tu es: Codigo/Paginas/experiencia.html   y  Codigo/estilo_experiencia.css    por tanto, prueba  href="../estilo_experiencia.css"

Comment: Muchas gracias Jair. Ayer estuve probando y pude solucionarlo. Saludos!